# Split a table file according to modification in a specific column

Tags: awk, split, gnu

I have this kind of table:

```
classA, s1, ss1
classA, s1, ss2
classA, s2, ss1
classB, s1, ss1
classB, s1, ss2
classC, s1, ss1
classC, s2, ss1
classC, s2, ss2
```

Which I would like to split in 3 files called "classA", "classB", and "classC", according to the consecutive values in 1st column. I tried first to find a way to do that using csplit, but it seems to work only on a specified pattern, not when the pattern changes. Is there any awk way or any other command-line tool to do that?

[UPDATE]
I have also some slashes in my 1st column that lead to that error, example:

```
classA, s1, ss1
classA, s1, ss2
classA, s2, ss1
classB, s1, ss1
classB, s1, ss2
classC, s1, ss1
classC, s2, ss1
classC, s2, ss2
classA/classA.1/classA.2, s1, ss1
classA/classA.1/classA.2, s1, ss2
```

And when I run the command:

```
awk -F, '{ print $0 > $1}' infile
```

It works with until "classC" but then I have that error because I guess it interprets the "/" as a path:

```
fatal: can't redirect to `classA/classA.1/classA.2' (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F, '{ print $0 > $1}' infile
```

**output**

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 shellter root  48 Sep 13 14:01 classC
-rw-r--r-- 1 shellter root  32 Sep 13 14:01 classB
-rw-r--r-- 1 shellter root  48 Sep 13 14:01 classA
```

where $1 has "/.../path/info, try

```
awk -F, '{ outFile="$1"; gsub(/\//, "", outFile); print $0 > outFile }' infile
```

If you don't do the `gsub()`, any '/' chars will be intrepreted to follow a path to create the output file. Of course the path specfied will need to exist, or you'll get error messages to that affect.

Note that some awks prefer to have the '/' char like `gsub(/[\/]/,"", fileName)`, or you might even need `[\\/]` as the search target.

IHTH

Comment: This script creates only one file, called "$1", which is a copy of my infile.

Comment: I have in the first column some values with a '/' which makes trouble when writing the corresponding file. Is there a way to get around that sub-problem?

Comment: please edit your Q with exact error message, and 1 record with the new requirement.

Comment: The problem is that they're not a path. But that's fine, I'll sed it before and after, something like: sed 's/\//;/g' infile | awk -F, '{ print $0 > $1}' ; sed -i 's/;/\//g' *

Comment: @LostInTranslation: No need to use `sed`. Use AWK's `gsub` function. In any case, there's no need for the `sed` at the end since there's no output to `stdout` in the AWK command.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson OK I see, but could you paste an example? I tried without any success...

Comment: `sub("str", "repl", $0)` is equivalent to `sed 's/str/repl/', which `gsub("str","repl",$0)` is equivalent to `sed 's/str/repl/g'`, g=global  for both sed and awk `gsub`. See my updates.

Comment: @LostInTranslation: see shelter's comment immediately above.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The use of "[]" was mandatory in my case, that's why I could not succeed in my first attempt.